# javascript to check a link for string & launch modal

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

Have a page containing links.

When a link is clicked I want Javascript (or other) to check if the link contains (e.g. cheese)

If if does, then a modal should launch displaying the link.

example:

http://mylink/just-normal/ -- when this clicked, should proceed as normal

http://mylink/with-cheese/ -- when this clicked, should launch modal

http://mylink/another-link/ -- when this clicked, should proceed as normal

http://mylink/other-link/ -- when this clicked, should proceed as normal

Modal should display the full link.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Below is what I've got so far.

My specific question is: 
**Question:** When I click any link on the site, a modal opens. It seems to be targeting all links and not just the links containing the specific word(s).

```
   jQuery(function () {


jQuery(document).on('click', jQuery('a') , function(event){

    var e = event;  
    event.preventDefault;
    var that = event.target;
    if(jQuery(that).is("span")){
        that = jQuery(event.target).parent();   
    }
    if(jQuery(that).attr('href')){
        var url = jQuery(that).attr('href').toLowerCase();
        if(jQuery.browser.webkit || jQuery.browser.mozilla && (url.indexOf('.my.test.here/') >=0)) {
            ie_pointer(e, that);
        }
        else if (jQuery.browser.webkit && || jQuery.browser.mozilla (url.indexOf('something.else/') >=0)){
            var overall = jQuery('.overall');
            ie_pointer(e, overall, that);
        }
    }       
});

});

function ie_pointer(event, obj, that){
    event.preventDefault();
    if(that){
    var url = jQuery(that).attr('href');
    }
    else{
    var url = jQuery(obj).attr('href');
    }
    jQuery('<div class="modal-backdrop"></div>').hide().appendTo(document.body).fadeIn();
    jQuery(obj).after('<div class="modal-content" style="padding:10px"><h3 style="color:#333">Please copy the blue link below into Internet Explorer</h3><p style="font-size: 1.2rem; color:#333">This form is currently unavailable in Firefox & Chrome.</p><h4 style="color: #0099cc; max-width: 400px; word-wrap:break-word;">'+url+'</h4><i onclick="close_modal()" class="icon-remove"></i></button></div>');
}

function close_modal(){
    jQuery(".modal-backdrop").fadeOut(function(){jQuery(this).remove()});
    jQuery('.modal-content').fadeOut(function(){jQuery(this).remove()});
    }
```

Comment: *Have a page containing links.* Please always include the code you are working with in your question. We can't help you without that. In addition, Stack Overflow is not a place to posts requests for code to be written. Your question isn't really a question, it's a request for us to write a solution for you. We don't do that here.

Comment: Thanks for the response Scott. Sorry about that. I know my code is poor and didn't want to influence anyone who might want to help with a simpler solution or a different approach. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Yes, but you still really aren't asking a ***specific*** question, which is what Stack Overflow is for. You're saying "this is what I want and here's how far I've gotten. Can you write the rest for me?". That's not what we do here. If you have a ***specific*** question/problem, post that, along with what you've tried and what the results were.

Comment: Thanks again for the feedback. I have now updated the above with my specific question. (still got my training wheels on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your click event handler is set up for event delegation so that it only responds when `event.target` is an `<a>`:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', jQuery('a') , function(event){
```

Yet, inside of the handler, you have this:

```
if(jQuery(that).is("span")){
    that = jQuery(event.target).parent();   
}
```

Since you have `that` set to `event.target`, this `if` condition will never be `true`, so I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish with it.

The remainder of the function runs when the `<a>` element has an `href`, but there too, you have `if` conditions that don't quite make sense:

```
if(jQuery.browser.webkit || 
   jQuery.browser.mozilla && (url.indexOf('.my.test.here/') >=0)) {
      ie_pointer(e, that);
} else if (jQuery.browser.webkit && || 
           jQuery.browser.mozilla (url.indexOf('something.else/') >=0)){
      var overall = jQuery('.overall');
      ie_pointer(e, overall, that);
}
```

Your first condition will be `true` if the browser is `webkit` or if it is `mozilla` and the attribute contains your test string. Why don't you want to test for the string when the browser is `webkit`?

Your `else if` condition does the same thing, but you have a syntax error in it because you forget `&&` here:

```
jQuery.browser.mozilla (url.indexOf('something.else/') >=0))
```

**And, perhaps more importantly, why do you care what browser it is?** JQuery **[deprecated the `browser` flags in version 1.9](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/)** because they are based on the `navigator.userAgent`, which has always been an unreliable way of browser sniffing.

---

Here's a slimmed down example of getting links that contain a certain string in their `href` to do one thing and all others to do something else using the standard **[CSS attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)**:

```js
var url = "console";

// Simply use the attribute wildcard selector to make sure
// you are only selecting links you care about in the first place
$("a[href*='" + url + "']").on("click", function(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
  alert("You clicked a link that I care about!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="console-1.html">I should cause an alert().</a><br>
<a href="one-console.html">I should cause an alert().</a><br>
<a href="con.html">I should NOT cause an alert().</a><br>
<a href="sole-1.html">I should NOT cause an alert().</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Scott for a most comprehensive answer. Not only did you answer my question, you took apart my "pretty bad" code and gave me an education along the way. Very much appreciated. This little grasshopper, indeed has a lot to learn. Thanks again.

Comment: @OffDutyNinja Well, I have been an IT trainer for 25 years, so it's hard for me not to teach when I answer. Glad you appreciated it!